# When do javascript GCP libraries return null?

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-platform

I'm working with GCP and Firebase using typescript. I'm using provided libraries (v8 in case of firebase) and I have noticed some weird behaviour

##### For example ([firebase](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase), ver. 8.10.1)

```js
import 'firebase/auth'
import firebase from 'firebase/app'

firebase.initializeApp({ apiKey: 'my-api-key', projectId: 'my-project-id' })
const auth = firebase.auth()

const { user } = await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword('example@email.com', 'example-password')
```

`signInWithEmailAndPassword` method returns an object of type `UserCredential` with all properties typed `Type | null`

```js
type UserCredential = {
  additionalUserInfo?: firebase.auth.AdditionalUserInfo | null;
  credential: firebase.auth.AuthCredential | null;
  operationType?: string | null;
  user: firebase.User | null;
};
```

Where is this `null` coming from? Based on my testing, these methods always return proper values or reject the promise with an error. I can't find a documented case where `null` is returned

##### The same with other libraries ([secret-manager](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/secret-manager), ver. 4.2.0)

```js
import { SecretManagerServiceClient } from '@google-cloud/secret-manager'

const secretManager = new SecretManagerServiceClient()

const [secretVersion] = await secretManager.accessSecretVersion({
  name: 'projects/p/secrets/secret-name/versions/latest'
})
```

Here again, return type looks like:

```js
interface IAccessSecretVersionResponse {
  name?: string | null;
  payload?: google.cloud.secretmanager.v1.ISecretPayload | null;
}
```

Where are those `null` values coming from? Under which circumstances could these libraries return `null` instead of an error?

Can someone explain this behaviour or point me to the correct place in the docs?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking this because you are having typescript intellisense issues while assigning the values returned by this library functions. And getting error something like in the IDE `Type 'X | null' is not assignable to type 'X'. Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'X'.`

The use of the `Type | null` in the return type for `UserCredential` and `IAccessSecretVersionResponse` is due to the possibility that the API may return null if the request fails or the data is not available.

Now as you have mentioned, these methods always return proper values or reject the promise with an error.  But there are other circumstances in which it will return null:

- Incorrect API usage: If the API is used in an incorrect manner, such as passing in an invalid parameter, it may return null.
- Network errors: If the API call encounters a network error, it may return null.
- Data not found: If the API cannot find the requested data, it may return null.
- Authorization errors: If the API call requires authorization and the provided credentials are invalid, it may return null.

While building any method for any library devs provide what will be expected returned, Corresponding Errors and null just for anything happens other than expected result and Errors like mentioned above.

This issue seems to be resolved or non-existence in [firebase V9](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase) (modular SDK) version.

The Official Reference for these methods are [signInWithEmailAndPassword](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.auth.Auth#signinwithemailandpassword) which returns Promise of [UserCredential](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.auth#usercredential) and same with SecretManagerServiceClient.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I don't think it answers my question. All cases you mentioned reject a promise or simply throw with a proper error message (except for user not found in firestore, which as a matter of fact returns `null`as documented). Also, in the docs you provided there is no mention of these `null` values and where they come from